# Are Heap and Priority Queue, data structures or abstract data types?

Tags: javascript, java, data-structures, adt

I have seen similar questions and read a lot of the answers. One would think that I would know it then, however some of the answers were contradictory and now I am more confused than when I started.

My quest started of as - what is the difference between a Heap and a Priority Queue. To where I learned that Heap was a data structure and Priority Queue was a abstract data type. But why?

So far I found this answer to be the best: **Simply put, the relation between data structure and abstract data type is the same as the relation between algorithm and pseudo-code. The first is an idea, the second a formal description (abstract, inaccessible).**

Some mention that ADT is a language dependent term. Since it describes “data types not included in the standard library”. So in Java or JS a Heap is not in the standard library, but previously I learned that heaps are a data structure and not an abstract data type?

Can someone clarify in general what a data structure and abstract data type is?

Comment: An abstract data type defines what you can do with it.  A data structure determines how it's done.  I can't imagine what you might mean by "and why?"

Comment: ADT is the API and data structure is the implementation? @MattTimmermans

Comment: @JonasGrønbek Yes, exactly that.

Comment: I found this answer - A priority queue is an abstract datatype. It is a shorthand way of describing a particular interface and behavior, and says nothing about the underlying implementation.

A heap is a data structure. It is a name for a particular way of storing data that makes certain operations very efficient.

Comment: So a heap is a data structure since it is canonically implemented in a specific way, and a priority queue is an ADT because has a lot of different implementations? 
When implemented the priority queue class would then be regarded as a data structure?

Comment: A priority queue is an ADT. It can be implemented with many different data structures, like a binary heap, fibonacci heap, linked list, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Priority Queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) is an abstract data type, it can be implemented in many different ways.

A [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) is a data structure, the way it stores data and how it works with it are both well defined.

Using a heap to implement a priority queue is a good idea because the way a heap operates on the data aligns very well with the way a priority queue works. If you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) for `java.util.PriorityQueue` you will see the following comment:

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority **heap**

You could think of an ADT as a high level logical description (what it does) while a data structure defines exactly how the data is stored and manipulated (how it's done).

Could you implement a priority queue using some other data structure? of course, probably not as efficiently though.

Comment: So java.util.PriorityQueue is a data structure since it is now implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need to use another data structure to implement your desired data structure, then your desired data structure is better described as ***ABSTRACT DATA STRUCTURE***.

Some examples of ADT are:

1. Stack
2. Queue
3. Deque
4. Priority Queue
5. Tree, etc

I hope this helps.